# PostgreSQL не отвечает на запросы

Tags: база-данных, postgresql

После нескольких запросов, СУБД перестает отвечать, и я уже не понимаю что делать... Вот логи[image: лог]

Перерыл весь гугл, ничего путного не нашел, конфиги не трогал, как стояли после установки, так и стоят.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы не указали ни используемую операционную систему, ни аппаратную архитектуру системы, ни версию postgresql. Даже логи в виде какой-то наскальной живописи.

Впрочем по [`CreateProcess call failed` очевидно](https://github.com/postgres/postgres/blob/REL_10_STABLE/src/backend/postmaster/postmaster.c#L4643), что у вас windows, это единственное место с таким текстом ошибки и этот код существует только для windows. [`CreateProcess`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/desktop/ms682425(v=vs.85).aspx) при этом - это вызов WinAPI функции. Если системный вызов возвращает ошибку - то база данных, да и любое приложение, ничего с этим сделать не может. Вопрос к вашей операционной системе.

Пачка замечаний `не удалось получить данные от клиента` в оригинале звучит как [`could not receive data from client`](https://github.com/postgres/postgres/blob/REL_10_STABLE/src/backend/libpq/pqcomm.c#L978) и ничем не примечательны: как поясняет дальнейший текст, клиент открывший это соединение потребовал закрыть соединение. Соответственно вопрос к приложению, открывшему соединение. Возможно оно некорректно обрабатывает отказ в новом соединении из-за вышеупомянутой ошибки winapi.

Ну а затем штатное выключение по команде администратора. То есть возможный интерес представляет ошибка `A blocking operation was interrupted by a call to WSACancelBlockingCall`, не имеющая отношения к базе данных, а только к вашей операционной системе. Не могу сказать, что это, такими экзотическими ОС не занимаюсь. Может быть какое-то [стороннее ПО причина](https://serverfault.com/a/593435), может быть нет памяти.

Повторяя [ответ core разработчика postgresql](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/CA%2BTgmoZZdD-b_V-vRMv5pHNZ7QqivCERUXhc3zMw3diHRNxFdw%40mail.gmail.com) на похожий багрепорт, очевидно, что проблема связана с отказом ОС в создании нового процесса, но это не происходит постоянно у всех других пользователей, значит причина в каком-то отличии вашей конкретной системы. Но вы не сообщили никаких деталей, чтобы предположить в чём именно это отличие может быть.